# vb 2008 Application calling Outlook with an Attachment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6-migration, office-automation

Have an application that I have the task of upgrading from VB6 to VB 2008.
The program has code that creates an Excel sheet and opens Outlook with the Excel sheet as an attachment.

My problem is there are 3 different versions of Outlook. I had it working from my laptop where I am developing at. I run Outlook 2013 but originally had 2010 office. Made the application a clickonce program. 
For people that are running 2010 and earlier outlook it was working. The Outlook 2013 throws the following exception:

Error loading type library/DLL (Exception from HRESULT:0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY).
Happens during this bit of code:

```
Dim Olook = New Outlook.Application()
Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem
Mail = Olook.CreateItemMicrosoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
```

Reading up on this I did find that when referencing Outlook 2013, the reference is in COM tab but other versions are .net.

Does anyone know how I might get them to both play together?
Excel is not having issue when I create the Excel workbook for the attachment

Comment: Note typo in my edit.  Should be `Mail = Olook.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem`

Comment: That is what I have . The error is being thrown on that line. This doesn't cause any issues with PCs running earlier versions of Outlook. The thing that is puzzling me is that prior to creating the olMailItem the program Creates and Opens Excel worksheet using Interop also. The PCs having the Outlook issue have no problem opening and saving file in Excel and Excel is also 2013 version .